# Async Task OnProgressUpdate CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am using an AsyncTask to download a database with a progressdialog that shows progress on the UI.  Some of my users are receiving the error:

CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

As I understand it, this should only happen if you are trying to update Views off of the UI thread.  Here is the error:

com...updateops.DbCreate.onProgressUpdate(DbCreate.java:70)
at com...updateops.DbCreate.onProgressUpdate(DbCreate.java:1)

and here is my code:

```
public class DbCreate extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

private static Context mCtx;
private static ProgressDialog mDialog;
public static AmazonSimpleDBClient mSDbClient;
public static AmazonS3Client mS3Client;
private static int mAppVersion;
private static boolean mCreate;


public DbCreate(Context ctx, int versionCode, boolean create) {
    mCtx = ctx.getApplicationContext();
    mAppVersion = versionCode;
    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mDialog.setMessage("Checking for server access. Please wait...");
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mDialog.setMax(1);
    mDialog.show(); 
    mCreate = create;

}

protected void onProgressUpdate(String... name) {
    if (name[0].equals("item")) {
        mDialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
    } else if (name[0].equals("setMax")) {
        mDialog.setProgress(0);
        mDialog.setMax(Integer.parseInt(name[1]));   <-- This is line 70
}}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    **do stuff**
    publishProgress("setMax", ""+ 3);
}
```

It looks to me like I am following exactly what I am supposed to do in order to avoid this error.  Anyone know why it's happening?

Edit:  I should also mention that this code works most of the time.  I am receiving crash reports on the Developer Console.

Comment: As error said, you can't touch (change/update) any view (controls: such as button, edittext etc.) out of main thread. I am not sure that but maybe you should try: mCtx.mDialog.setMax(Integer.parseInt(name[1]));

Comment: If that were required then this code would never work.  It is a crash report I am trying to find the root cause and solution of that affects a small percentage of my users.

Comment: may be , you are not calling this Async from UI thread .

Comment: I am calling it from the UI thread.  It is only called in a single place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the onProgressUpdate(Progress...) is invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...).

You should analyze the whole log report to check if there is any chance that your async task was **created on other thread**.

And if you really cannot find the root cause you can use a handler created on UI thread to workaround.

Comment: The handler solution worked.  I'm still not sure why this is happening (occurs only on select phones/OS version).  I can only duplicate it on my N1 running 2.3.3 but there are reports in the Developer Console as well.

Answer (score 1):

You code looks fine and in most of the cases it should work. I would suggest you to use handler. You can write a handler in UI thread and call it from onProgressUpdate(). This will completely ensure that the UI work is done in UI thread.

This will fix your issue for sure, but I dont know why you are gettin error at first hand. I have seen this kind of issue before and never got a concrete reason for it.

Comment: The handler solution worked but I had to give it to Robin since it was posted earlier.  I never did find the problem though...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that you are describing and I fixed it by using a `runOnUiThread()` call against the context owned by the AsyncTask (as you also have in your example).

The following solution should absolve your issues;

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... messages){
        myActivityReference.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {          
                // Your UI changes here. 
           }
       });                 
    }
```

It's worth noting that my `AsyncTask` was originally called from within a `AlertDialog`, which is what I believe is causing the issue to begin with.

Comment: This solved my problem, too, except I just ran `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()...` without the activity reference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue on Android 2.3.x devices and here's the crash log:

```
android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2934)
...
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

The log indicates that `onProgressUpdate` and `onPostExecute` are executed on `HandlerThread` which is essentially a worker thread with a custom `Looper`. So that's why the crash occurs.

Therefore, in your case it is likely the internal handler of `AsyncTask` is bound to non main looper associated with a worker thread like `HandlerThread` and `onUpdateProgress` is processed on worker thread instead.

I found this bug appear pervasively on Android 2.3 devices. Therefore I checked the source code of `AsyncTask` in 2.3 and found this:

```
private static final InternalHandler sHandler = new InternalHandler();

private static class InternalHandler extends Handler {
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "RawUseOfParameterizedType"})
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The chance is that the internal handler might be bound to a non main looper.

I also checked the latest source code of `AsyncTask` and saw the change:

```
private static class InternalHandler extends Handler {
    public InternalHandler() {
        super(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }
    ...
}
```

The `InternalHandler` constructor eliminate the chance that it might be bound to a non main looper therefore `onUpdateProgress` behaves normal on post Android 2.3 devices.